# setTimeout doesnt work as expected with synchronous ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a function that gets called multiple times as a result of looping through an array with length n and constructing `Plants` each of which uses synchronous ajax calls, and it queries the Google Maps API so I need to throttle it.  I set a `setTimeout()` on the function that calls the Geocoding with 5 seconds to be safe and nested that setTimeout in the done() function of the ajax. The problem is that the timeout is setting the delay and then proceeding to the next ajax call.  Then the first geocode is occurring 5 seconds after the first ajax finished.

```
function Plant(plantName, address, inventory){
    this.plantName = plantName;
    this.address = address;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.latCoord = 0;
    this.lngCoord = 0;

    this.pullCoordinatesFromDB();
}

Plant.prototype.pullCoordinatesFromDB = function(){
    var $this = this;
    console.log("pulling farm coords for: "+$this.address);
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            address: $this.address
        },
        url: "actions/getCoordinates.php"
    }).always(function(){
        console.log("request sent");
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("failed");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("got farm coords");
        if(data.numRows){
            $this.latCoord = data.latCoord;
            $this.lngCoord = data.lngCoord;
        }
        else{
            setTimeout( $this.pullCoordinatesFromAPI , 5000);
        }
    });
    return 1;
};

Plant.prototype.pullCoordinatesFromAPI = function(){
    var $this = this;
    GEOCODER.geocode( {'address': $this.address}, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            $this.latCoord = location.lat;
            $this.lngCoord = location.lng;
                console.log("pushing");
            $this.pushCoordinatesToDB();
        }
        else{
            console.log("Could not successfully query the API: "+status);
        }
    });
    return 1;
};
```

The output seems to be logging the outputs as:

- pulling farm coords for:
- request sent
- got farm coords
- pulling farm coords for:
- request sent
- got farm coords
- ...
- pulling farm coords for:
- request sent
- got farm coords
- plotted
- Could not sucessfully query the API: OVER_QUERY_LIMITS
- ......

Comment: `async: false,` is it really necessary?

Comment: side-note, the promise callbacks (done, fail, always, etc) are deprecated for synchronous requests.

Comment: If you want it all to run synchronously, just call the function without timeout?

Comment: pausing 5 seconds after the database call is not going to change you querying google. Problem is the fact you are calling `Plant` way too many times in a row.

Comment: @epascarello I am confused. Maybe I dont fully have a grasp on sync vs async but what I want is to check the database, if there isn't an entry there go to the api, then once accessed (either from the DB or API), start the next constructor for Plant. I thought ajax is by default async and therefore could run in the background without freezing the JS. I want it to freeze the JS so that it doesn't start the next call until the current one is done.

Comment: Than you need to change how you are making the calls. You either need to change how you loop [can't be a for loop] or you need to build up a queue of Ajax calls to make.

Comment: @epascarello why is a for loop not appropriate in this context? And how does my system not build up an ajax request queue? The cyclical returns wouldnt happen if they all fired at once, right? It would just say pulling farm coords a bunch then as they resolved it would sprinkle in the always and done commands.

Comment: @caeth I need the timeout because ajax calls to fast and each call resolves with the resulting api query quickly, making me go over my query limit

Comment: @KevinB If I removed the promise callbacks and simply had the timeout following the $.ajax() call would that address the issue? And if they are deprecated how do they recognize and fire?

Comment: @Cheery If I do not include async: false, they all call on top of each other, resolve at nearly the same time, and query the api at about the same time making them go over the limit. I thought if i made it synchronous it would allow me to inject the setTimeout() so the system would wait between ajax calls and their respective callback api queries

Comment: @TimoLoescher Yes, however it would have the side effect that if the requests take longer than 5 seconds, they can begin to pile up and eventually crash the client browser. use the `success: handler` option instead.

Comment: @KevinB i was confused by this in the API which I thought was saying the opposite: "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."

Comment: That's a different deprecation notice, not related to my suggestion. :) `success:` `error:` and `complete:` are not deprecated, `.success` `.error` and `.complete` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with [jQuery.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/), here's how you can do it:

```
var queue = $({});
var deferreds = [];

Plant.prototype.pullCoordinatesFromDB = function(dfd){
    var $this = this;
    console.log("pulling farm coords for: "+$this.address);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            address: $this.address
        },
        url: "actions/getCoordinates.php"
    }).always(function(){
        console.log("request sent");
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("failed");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("got farm coords");
        if(data.numRows){
            $this.latCoord = data.latCoord;
            $this.lngCoord = data.lngCoord;
        }
        else{
            queue.delay(5000).queue(function(next){
                $this.pullCoordinatesFromAPI();
                dfd.resolve();
                next();
            });
        }
    });
    return 1;
};

var plants = [Plant, Plant, ...];
for(var i = 0; i < plants.length; ++i){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    plants[i].pullCoordinatesFromDB();
    deferreds.push(dfd);
}

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
```

EDIT: Added deferreds to see when all calls from api are done.

Comment: Thanks! I had never seen jQuery queue before!

Comment: Every time I create a Plant it gets the values from the database or API. In my code where I call Plant multiple times, I am adding those plants into an array FULL_LIST. Then I want to do work with FULL_LIST by performing mathematical calculations on the properties of various Plants.  Is it possible to wait until all those Plants are thoroughly created (like waiting until the end of the queue) to continue in my main script?

Comment: @TimoLoescher You can do that with `jQuery.Deferred`, see my updated answer.